# Can't figure out how to print * & whitespace vertically instead of hoirzontally

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried looking at other threads but still couldn't figure it out.

I am using this code:

```
numbers = [5,1,5,2,4]

for i in numbers:
  for x in range(0,i):
    print "*",
  print""
```

It prints:

```
* * * * * 
* 
* * * * * 
* *
* * * *
```

etc.

I would like it to print:

```
    *   *
    *   *   *
    *   *   *
    *   * * *
    * * * * *
```

I understand i must use `if` statements for whitespace or *

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
numbers = [5,1,5,2,4]

for h in range(max(numbers), 0, -1):
   for x in numbers:
      if x >= h:
        print '*',
      else:
        print ' ',
   print ""
```

or a shorter version.

```
for h in range(max(numbers), 0, -1):
    print ' '.join('*' if x >= h else ' ' for x in numbers)
```

Comment: Missing a space in the else case.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, you can even use `*` for 3 different things!

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> for x in reversed(list(izip_longest(*['*'*n for n in numbers], fillvalue=' '))):
...     print ' '.join(x)
... 
*   *    
*   *   *
*   *   *
*   * * *
* * * * *
```

Answer (score 2):

```
numbers = [5,1,5,2,4]

for m in xrange(max(numbers)-1,0,-1):
  line = map (lambda x : '*' if x >= m else ' ' , numbers)
  print " ".join(line)
```

Comment: The stop in `xrange` should be zero or it prints an extra `*` in each column less than max.